# Scaling a graph of a circle and the standard parabola in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code renders the graphs of an arc of a circle and the standard parabola on the Cartesian plane. It is ridiculously small, though. How do I magnify the display, except for the labels on the axes? (I do not want to use `pgfplots`.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}



\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%An arc of a circle centered at (0, 1/2) and the standard parabola are drawn on the Cartesian plane.
\draw[fill] (0,1/2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[blue] ($(0,1/2) +(150:1/2)$) arc (150:390:1/2);
\draw[domain={-sqrt(3)/2}:{sqrt(3)/2}] plot (\x, {\x*\x});
\draw[latex-latex] ($(-12.5pt,0) +({-1/sqrt(2)},0)$) -- ($(12.5pt,0) +({1/sqrt(2)},0)$);
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-1/2) -- ($(0,3/4) +(0,12.5pt)$);
\node[below right] at ($({1/sqrt(2)}, 0) +(12.5pt,0)$){\textit{x}};
\node[above right] at ($(0,3/4) +(0,12.5pt)$){\textit{y}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

- I add `scale` option. I think `scale=5` is appropriate in this case.
- I don't use your approach to center figures. I would use `figure` and add a caption as well as a label instead. If you don't want a caption and a label, you should use `center` environment.
- I changed a `\draw[fill]` to `\fill`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
%An arc of a circle centered at (0, 1/2) and the standard parabola are drawn on the Cartesian plane.
\fill (0,1/2) circle (0.3pt); % Note that it is not 1.5pt (fixed below)
\draw[blue] ($(0,1/2) +(150:1/2)$) arc (150:390:1/2);
\draw[domain={-sqrt(3)/2}:{sqrt(3)/2}] plot (\x, {\x*\x});
\draw[latex-latex] ($(-12.5pt,0) +({-1/sqrt(2)},0)$) -- ($(12.5pt,0) +({1/sqrt(2)},0)$);
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-1/2) -- ($(0,3/4) +(0,12.5pt)$);
\node[below right] at ($({1/sqrt(2)}, 0) +(12.5pt,0)$){\textit{x}};
\node[above right] at ($(0,3/4) +(0,12.5pt)$){\textit{y}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{fig:tikzfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or if you want to have your image automatically resized to `\textwidth`, have a look at the nice `tikzscale` package.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mypic.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%An arc of a circle centered at (0, 1/2) and the standard parabola are drawn on the Cartesian plane.
\fill (0,1/2) circle (0.3pt);
\draw[blue] ($(0,1/2) +(150:1/2)$) arc (150:390:1/2);
\draw[domain={-sqrt(3)/2}:{sqrt(3)/2}] plot (\x, {\x*\x});
\draw[latex-latex] ($(-12.5pt,0) +({-1/sqrt(2)},0)$) -- ($(12.5pt,0) +({1/sqrt(2)},0)$);
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-1/2) -- ($(0,3/4) +(0,12.5pt)$);
\node[below right] at ($({1/sqrt(2)}, 0) +(12.5pt,0)$){\textit{x}};
\node[above right] at ($(0,3/4) +(0,12.5pt)$){\textit{y}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mypic.tikz}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{fig:tikzfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

[First code improved]

I suggest not using a filled circle for coordinate. A `node` is more ok I think. Also a `node` is not scaled by `scale`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\tikzset{your coordinate/.style={fill=black,inner sep=0.5pt,circle}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
%An arc of a circle centered at (0, 1/2) and the standard parabola are drawn on the Cartesian plane.
\node[your coordinate] at (0,1/2) {};
\draw[blue] ($(0,1/2) +(150:1/2)$) arc (150:390:1/2);
\draw[domain={-sqrt(3)/2}:{sqrt(3)/2}] plot (\x, {\x*\x});
\draw[latex-latex] ($(-12.5pt,0) +({-1/sqrt(2)},0)$) -- ($(12.5pt,0) +({1/sqrt(2)},0)$);
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-1/2) -- ($(0,3/4) +(0,12.5pt)$);
\node[below right] at ($({1/sqrt(2)}, 0) +(12.5pt,0)$){\textit{x}};
\node[above right] at ($(0,3/4) +(0,12.5pt)$){\textit{y}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{fig:tikzfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can (should) also apply this to the second code. Btw, I think your circle is way too small.

Comment: I agree that magnifying by 5 is appropriate. (I see that you had to manually calculate the radius of the dot indicating the center of the circle with the `scale` option.)

Comment: What is the advantage of using the `figure` environment? I see that you used that in both codes.

Comment: With the option `width=\textwidth`, is the height of the figure also `\textwidth`?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire For comment (2): It is a floating environment, so you can control the position of the environment to the top of the page, the bottom, etc. with floating options. Moreover, you can make a caption and a label, so you can make a reference to the figure (e.g. We have figure 1 so...) later.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire For comment (3) (you are typing so fast :D) No. Unless your Ti*k*Z picture is in the shape of a square.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire I edited my answer. Now the radius of the dot is prevented from being scaled.

Answer (score 3):

Another option that might help if you want to save `scale` for relative scaling and/or are using `transform shape` is just to redefine the unit vectors. In this example, this is equivalent to [Joule V's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484158/121799), but in the above-mentioned situations it might be useful to know about this option, too.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5cm,y=5cm]
\draw[fill] (0,1/2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[blue] ($(0,1/2) +(150:1/2)$) arc (150:390:1/2);
\draw[domain={-sqrt(3)/2}:{sqrt(3)/2}] plot (\x, {\x*\x});
\draw[latex-latex] ($(-12.5pt,0) +({-1/sqrt(2)},0)$) -- ($(12.5pt,0) +({1/sqrt(2)},0)$);
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-1/2) -- ($(0,3/4) +(0,12.5pt)$);
\node[below right] at ($({1/sqrt(2)}, 0) +(12.5pt,0)$){$x$};
\node[above right] at ($(0,3/4) +(0,12.5pt)$){$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do the options `x=5cm, y=5cm` for the `TikZ` environment render `\coordinate (center_of_circle) at (0,1/2);` as a point `2.5cm` above the origin?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Yes, as can be seen from the output.

Comment: This is a very short edit to my code to give me the display that I want.